# How to show html content perfectly after converting excel content to html type?

Tags: html, r, excel

I hava a data of excel type and I wanna convert it into  html type and show it in webpage.

Now I can convert the excel to html. But when I open the html in web it doesn't work so perfectly

Just like this below:
[image]

But I have the perfect one like this below.It can show in web in center:
[image]

Here is my sample data:

```
sample information  
                               GSE95401_EAE_Acute
Original publication title     Profiling the mouse brain endothelial transcriptome in health and 
                               disease models reveals a core blood-brain barrier dysfunction 
                               module
PMID                           31611708
Data source                    https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE95401
Disease/Treatment              EAE was induced by injecting the MOG35–55 peptide containing emulsion.
Species                        Mus musculus
Strain                         C57BL/6-Rosa-tdTomato
Age                            2-3 months
Organ                          Spinal Cord
EC isolation method            fluorescence-activated cell sorting (FACS)
Treated group information      EAE Acute(Acute timepoints were taken on the first day that mice 
                               displayed a loss of 1 gram body weight.)
Treated group replication no.  3
Control group information      EAE control
Control group replication no.   3
```

I don't know how to deal with my problem. If I show edit it in html format ？Or use other right method ?

If I shouldn't  use excel to convert to html ?
Who can help me? Vary thankful!!

Comment: The only difference I can see is that your "perfect" example is centered, and has hortizontal lines between the rows. It's just a matter of presentation. Take a look at `kableExtra`, which I recommend for displaying tables in R / HTML.

Comment: @mhovd Ok.I have a try. Thanks.